# How to check network response is from Cache or Server in Alamofire request?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am making network calls using Alamofire and caching response in iOS app.

response is caching, but I am not able to check whether received response is from Cache or Server?

How to check the same?

Comment: Can you show your code so i can tell you?

Comment: In dataTaskWillCacheResponseWithCompletion I am setting response  headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=60"

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is any cached data for a request is available or not using.

```
if let cacheData = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: request) {

  // Already cached
}
```

Comment: I checked with same but always gives me - response is from server even when I hit offline request and get data from cache. below is code.                                            //Its Alamofire request                                                                                                                                                    if let cacheData = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: (request.request?.urlRequest!)!) {
                    print("Data is from cache")
                }else{
                    print("Data is from Server")
                }